# jQuery simulate tabbing: use keypress event to check for focus and advance to next

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form. The user presses enter. Their keypress is captured, and I'd like my script to advance focus to the next visible form element in the current form.

My current idea is that I need to get the list of inputs to cycle focus through, but I'm stuck on the concept of advancing--like, how do I figure out what the "next" one that it needs to go to is? Here's my code so far.

```
$('.myitems input').on('keydown', function(e){
  if ( e.which == 13 ) {

    // Get list of items I want to iterate through
    var fields = $('.myitems input:visible');

    // ...Now what...
  }

});
```

I'd basically like to shift focus to the next visible input in the set of items. I'm guessing that in order to do this I need to scan those items, figure out which one has focus, then assign focus to the next one in the list.

But I can't think of any way to do this in a reasonably performance efficient manner. Any ideas?

Comment: So, why not `$(this).next('input').focus()` ?

Comment: See, this is what you guys are here for -_- If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will cycle focus amongst sibling inputs. I use `nextAll` just in case there's something else besides the `input`.

```js
$('input.items').on('keydown', function(e){
  if ( e.which == 13 ) {
   var $next = $(this).nextAll('input');
    if($next.length === 0){
      $next = $(this).siblings('input');
    }
    $next.first().focus();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="items" type="text"> <br>
  <input class="items" type="text"> <br/>
  <input class="items" type="text"> <br/>
  </form>
```